# Chrome extension addEventListener + dispatchEvent result to var

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have background.js:

```
var responses = {}

var filter = {
  urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  types: ["main_frame"]
}

var options = ["responseHeaders"]

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
  responses[details.url] = details
}, filter, options)

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  sendResponse({
    headers: responses[sender.tab.url]
  })
})
```

ScriptForParsing.js

```
var markup;
var cookies;
var headers;

$(document).ready(function() {
  parse();
});

function parse() {
  markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
  cookies = document.cookie;

  document.addEventListener('GetHeaders', function(event) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chrome.runtime.id, {}, {}, function(response) {
      document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("GotHeaders",{
        detail: response.headers
      }))
    })
  })

}
```

I want that my var headers be like response.headers - how?

Comment: 1) It's not clear why you use GetHeaders and GotHeaders events - nothing in your posted code uses them - why not simply chrome.runtime.sendMessage({}, r => { headers = r.headers }), 2) it's possible sender.tab.url is already different if it was changed by the page script via DOM History API or due to a different #hash part - consider using tab id as a key in `responses`.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you fast code it?